# Local Notification getting triggered immediately

Tags: java, android

i have used the following code to trigger local notification in android.

```
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NewPaymentReminder.this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(Month_only));
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(Year_only));
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(Date_only));

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            //  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, secs);
            cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

            System.out.println("Calender - Get time in Milliseconds" + cal.getTimeInMillis());

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

RECEIVER CLASS:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyPaymentReminder.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyPaymentReminder.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Payment Reminder")
                .setContentText("New Notification")
                .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

I have registered my receiver in Manifest as well as i received the data in Receiver class. But my problem is i want to trigger notification at particular date and time but its triggering immediately! Any help would be greatly appreciated friends!

Answer (score 0):

Check if

```
System.out.println("Calender - Get time in Milliseconds" + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

is printing time in a future.

Also you should use alarmManager.setExact if you are targeting ApiLevel above 19. : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: I have set time triggering time to 04:29 and cal.getTimeInMillis() is returning a value -61622604035261. Its returning a negative value Drake

Comment: Check if you are setting correct year, as far as I see you are setting 0017 year not 2017

Comment: I found the solution@Drake, instead of above, i just find the difference between two dates in secs and sent it to alarm manager! Now, its working fine! Thanks @Drake!